# Не могу получить значение из базы данных

Tags: java, android, sql

Здравствуйте. Есть бд в которой лежат записи адресов сайтов, паролей и еще одной штуки. Нужно получить эту штуку если запись с адресом и паролем имеется. Если нет - получить пустую строку. Написал метод

```
public String getSave(String url, String key) {

    String[] columns = { Database.URL, Database.KEY, Database.SAVE};
    String selection = Database.URL + " =?" + " AND " + Database.KEY + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { url, key };
    Cursor cursor = db.query("save", columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, "1");
    String save;
    if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
        save = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.SAVE);
        cursor.close();
    }
    else save = "";
    return save;
}
```

Передаю в метод ссылку и пароль. Если записи с такими данными есть, то беру значение из `Database.SAVE`, если нет - пустая строка. Что не так то? Еще и лог странный

```
CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас возвращается пустой курсор. При этом неправильно указано условие в `if` из-за чего код не соответствует описанию.

[Cursor.moveToFirst](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) возвращает false если данных нет. Ваш код в этом случае пытается получить значение.

Скорее всего, должно быть наоборот:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    save = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.SAVE);
} else {
    save = "";
}
```