# Как приостановить диалог, если появилась ошибка?

Tags: java, android

**Дано:** диалоговое окно, при нажатии кнопки `OK` происходит добавление данных в бд

**Нужно** сделать так чтоб, если выпало исключение вывести сообщение (другое диалоговое окно "Запись уже существует!")

**Вопрос:** как это реализовать?

**Важно**: чтоб при нажатии кнопки ОК первое диалоговое окно не закрылось

```
private void showAddArticleDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_article_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

    String title = "";
    //String message = "Enter text below";

    if (TYPE) {
        title = getString(R.string.title_add_income_article);
    } else {
        title = getString(R.string.title_add_cost_article);
    }
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    //dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            try {
                myDb.addCategory(edt.getText().toString(), R.drawable.star, TYPE);
            } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showMessage(getString(R.string.this_article_exists));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            initializeAdapter();
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Про закрытие окна -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Вам надо в метод `setPositiveButton` в качестве второго аргумента (слушателя) передать `null`, затем создать `AlertDialog`. Потом повесить слушатель на показ в котором надо получить кнопку и повесить на нее слушатель. Потом окно показать.

```
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setView(v)
    .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
    .create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Do something
            //Dismiss once everything is OK.
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
});
```

2. Про проверку на уже существующую запись - я недавно задавал -> [Не могу получить значение из базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633086/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)